# How this animation is done?

Tags: css, animation, parallax

I am a newbie HTML developer and haven't worked on jQuery/CSS animations yet.
I have a question regarding the effect on the following link:
http://highline.huffingtonpost.com/miracleindustry/americas-most-admired-lawbreaker/

When page scrolls, the main image in header resizes (zoom out effect)
What is this animation, is it something Parallax or simply a CSS animation and how can I make this, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's using CSS transform, translate 3D. Look into using the Chrome element inspector to see how it works.

Comment: Yes, I see the value changes dynamically when scroll, is this with some jQuery etc?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial, technique or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can do using CSS3 and JQuery Parallax..

check this [sample](https://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/)